# How to check a checkbox based on DB query result in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query that brings selected values from the DB (i.e. preferences that were entered by user through around 20 checkboxes):

```php
$brng_selected = DB::table('Cprefs')
    ->where('user_id', $u_id)
    ->get();
return view('prefCat', ['b_sel' => $brng_selected]);
```

In the following example the user selected a preference with an id of 11 which refers to "sports" (in qatype field):

```
array(1) {
    [
        0
    ]=> object(stdClass)#368 (6) {
        [
            "id"
        ]=> int(47) [
            "created_at"
        ]=> string(19) "2019-09-27 12:29:59" [
            "updated_at"
        ]=> string(19) "2019-09-27 12:29:59" [
            "user_id"
        ]=> int(12) [
            "qatype"
        ]=> int(11) [
            "type"
        ]=> int(1)
    }
}
```

Now I need to configure the sports checkbox below to be checked based on the above. How can this be done?

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=11 > Sports<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=1> Politics<br>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: How you generate checkboxes ? dynamic or static?

Comment: static check boxes

Comment: And you get selected value from DB and want it checked if ID exists,right

Comment: This is correct

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the column which you need to compare as below

```
$brng_selected = DB::table('Cprefs')
    ->select('qatype') // column name which you need
    ->where('user_id', $u_id)
    ->get()->toArray(); // it will return as array

return view('prefCat', ['b_sel' => $brng_selected]);
```

In your view change as below :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=11 {{ (in_array(11,$brng_selected)?"checked":'') }} > Sports<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```php
@if ($ba_sel->qa_type == 11)
    <input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value="11" checked>Sports<br>
@else
    <input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value="11">Sports<br>
@endif
```

Comment: Yes but `checked` instead of `selected`

Comment: Are your checkboxes generated dynamicaly?

Comment: Undefined variable: item. I changed it to $b_sel , but gave me error : Undefined index: qatype

Comment: $item was just for the example, in your case, it must be $b_sel[0]['qatype']. Now on to the question, if the checkboxes are static, I do not see another way of doing this.